# Testing Mono for Mac

Tags: macos, mono

I am confused about how to test Mono for Mac...where is this file called hello.cs that I am supposed to edit? I don't know how to use these instructions, not familiar with programming. I am familiar with Terminal, but see no mention of using Terminal. 
I am using this app per instructions in the program iTunes2Spotify, on a Macbook Air (Mojave OS),

Comment: What test do you want to do? From where did you get hello.cs? Edit your question to make it valid.

Comment: Your question isn't really in the scope of StackOverflow. That said, I assume you've installed `mono` and are trying to validate the installation as per these instructions: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics? That seems unnecessary. To check if `mono` is installed, just try running `mono --version` at the Terminal. Otherwise, just try running your iTunes2Spotify program and if you have problems, maybe post a follow up question on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: please mention the URL where you read about the "hello.cs" file, otherwise we don't have context and cannot help you